# firebase_tools not found when trying to remove firestore collection from cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to remove a collection using callable firebase function.

I took a sample code from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections#cloud_function).

The sample code has a "firebase_tools" element.

```
        return firebase_tools.firestore
            .delete(path, {
                project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
                recursive: true,
                yes: true,
                token: functions.config().fb.token
            })
```

Which apparently is not part of `firebase-function`
I am getting following error in function logs:

`Unhandled error ReferenceError: firebase_tools is not defined`

The document also mentions that:

> You can import any function of the Firebase CLI into your own Node.js application using the firebase-tools package.

But I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Edit: Learning nodejs basics will help you a lot when working with firebase functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you look in the same document you refer to, you will find a link to the sample code: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/tree/master/firestore/solution-deletes

Then if you look at the Cloud Function code ([`index.js`](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/master/firestore/solution-deletes/functions/index.js)) you will see that this sample starts as follows:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();
```

So you need to:

- Firstly, check you have the [`firebase-tools`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools?activeTab=versions) package correctly installed. Normally this should be the case since you are most probably already using the Firebase CLI (see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools). In case not, install it with `npm i firebase-tools`.
- Secondly, import it in your Cloud Function with `const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');` as shown in the sample.

You will then be able to call `firebase_tools.firestore.delete()`.