# Where can I find documentation about firebase-tools.firestore.delete?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

In the guide for Firestore on [deleting a whole collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections#solution_delete_data_with_a_callable_cloud_function), there is an example using `firebase_tools.firestore.delete`. Where can I find documentation about this function? I only found it mentioned in the [CLI reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands) but with little detail.

Comment: You learn this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

Comment: I don't think there's a lot more documentation. What do you want to know about the function?

Comment: @Tomasz Vizaint: thank you for the pointer but this page does not provide much info on the firebase_tools.firestore.delete CLI function

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: As I would like to use this function in my app, I am interested in learning more about what the recursive delete does: does it delete subcollections as well, what are its limitation, for ex: max number of documents deleted, and how to use it with emulators

Comment: Note that you can programmatically use the Firebase CLI but only as a standard Node module. For example, you cannot use it like the JavaScript SDK from a Web/JS app. If you want to use the recursive deletion, you would need to write a Cloud Function and call it from your app. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55916960/3371862 for a bit more details.

Comment: Thank you Renaud Tarnec, using the firebase-tools as a node module as you detail in the mentioned is exactly my plan, but I do not feel very confident about it, for example: what would happen if the collection is too large and the cloud function times out. That is why I was looking at additional info. I am still looking for the equivalent of a loyal DELETE FROM table WHERE 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the `firebase-tools` library is only used in the CLI to Firebase projects. So the documentation for that command is in the reference docs for the CLI, but its admittedly a bit lightweight for the [Firestore delete command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands).

Luckily the `firebase-tools` library is open-source, so you can check exactly what it does by looking at the code. The `firestore:delete` command is implemented [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/72f6ff726f843342556375c1b99beb1c7baada84/src/commands/firestore-delete.ts) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/72f6ff726f843342556375c1b99beb1c7baada84/src/firestore/delete.js).

If you run into specific problems while implementing similar functionality, or have specific questions about it, I recommend posting those specific problems/questions. For example: the command indeed deletes subcollections.

Comment: Thank you, it is cool to see the code, and I got some info from the CLI help messages. As a side note, I agree that I should be more specific in my questions.

Comment: No worries there, as it's useful to share these links and showing that `firebase-tools` is a library and not just the CLI. It was mostly a "if you have a more specific problem, we can probably help more concretely". :)